# Infinite scroll for datagrid in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagrid, infinite-scroll

I am using Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid for implement data grid in my application, now I want to implement infinite scroll for that data grid. Can anyone please help me for how to implement infinite scroll behavior for data grid in xamarin forms?
My implementation for infinite scrolling is like

```
public class GridInfiniteScrollBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsLoadingMoreProperty;

    public GridInfiniteScrollBehavior()
    {

    }
    public bool IsLoadingMore { get; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(DataGrid bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(DataGrid bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve it? Have you made any efforts by yourself? If so, where are you stuck? This is not your personal 'we will code your solution for you'-service, but a community that helps with *specific* programming issues. Please see [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @PaulKertscher can you please check my question now

Comment: Well, you've implemented a `Behavior`, that actually does nothing. Honestly I see no attempt to implement infinite scrolling.

Comment: Is that the SyncFusion `DataGrid`?

Comment: Rather [this one](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid), right? You should add that detail to your question.

Comment: I am new to Xamarin,I don't know how to implement for infinite scrolling.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid for implementing datagrid.

Comment: Step 1: Load Data, Step 2: Detect that the user has scrolled to the end, Step 3: Load more data. Bonus hint: Use `ObservableCollection` and bind to it.

Comment: Another hint: Surround your `Grid` with a `ScrollView` and use [`Scrolled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scroll-view#events) event to detect if the user has scrolled to the end

Comment: @PaulKertscher Thanks for your help, I will check that